# How can I get integer value from activity-launcher to activity-default

Tags: android

I want to get value from user in launcher activity and use it in default activity for loop.

Comment: Show some work around than throwing question just like that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass values from your "LauncherActivity:"

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DefaultActivity.class);
i.putExtra("cycles",5);
startActivity(i);
```

Then retrieve those values in the "DefaultActivity":

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
int cycles = 0;
if (extras != null) {
    cycles = extras.getInt("cycles");
}
for (int i = 0; i < cycles: i++) {
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: Thanks dear for help